# I'm confused about the difference between pip and pip3, in anaconda env

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

TL;DR: a package is installed under pip3, but it cannot be found under Python3. Why?

All of this is happening in my anaconda base environemnt:

So I've been struggling with tensorflow and its versions (another post coming up).Turns out version 2.1 is only available at pip and not with conda install. So after upgrading `pip3 install --upgrade pip` I install `pip3 install tensorflow==2.1.0`. I open Jupyer-Notebook afterwards, and turns out tensorflow is not installed(running Python3). I check from the terminal first for the version, and then to uninstall tensorflow. It is not installed under pip (as expected) but it is indeed installed under pip3. I also get this message when uninstalling via pip3:

"`pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.`"

which might be related. I was under the impression that pip installs packages for the default python (3.7.4 in my case) but pip3 installs them only for Python3. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a package is installed under pip3, but it cannot be found under Python3. Why?

Because you have many different Pythons. `pip` doesn't install packages for all Pythons; `pip3` doesn't install packages for Python3. They install packages for that particular Pythons they're running under. You cannot expect to install a package with one Python and import it in another eve if they're of the same version.

To see what Python is used with a particular `pip` see its [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
head -1 $(which pip)
head -1 $(which pip3)
```

If the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python` continue investigating with `which python` (or `which python3`).

Finding the Python run `python -m site` to see where from the packages are imported.